# Block HTTP Access

Tags: http, blocking, blacklist, internet-filter

Is there a way on my Windows XP machine to blacklist certain HTTP URLS so that embedded web service calls won't trigger activity from my PC to those URLs?

Comment: Yes, install one of the myriad of personal security suites that do HTTP filtering.

Answer (score 4):

Firewalls or packet filtering are often a good solution for things like this.

One hack solution would be to specify entries for the hostnames directing to localhost in `C:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`.

For example:

`127.0.0.1 www.google.com` would prevent all access to www.google.com.

Comment: adding those bogus entries to the hosts file didn't seem to have any effect at all. :-(

Comment: Restart the Web browser.  Caching sometimes takes affect.

Comment: if it's being pesky, shut down the web browser, then type 'ipconfig /flushdns' to clear your dns cache, then reopen your browser

Answer (score 0):

One standard way is to put entries in your hosts.txt file that redirect
the offending domain names.  Handy for blocking ads for instance.

ie, in  `\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts.txt`

```
127.0.0.1 youclick2earn.com
```

for extra credit, install apache locally and capture all URLs so you can
display [ad] instead of a broken link.